# Add Show Problems View to RCP menu, but hide keyboard shortcut

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I added a command to show the problems view to my RCP application using the following snippet in plugin.xml

```
        <command
              commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
              label="Show Problems"
              style="push">
           <parameter
                 name="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.viewId"
                 value="org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView">
           </parameter>
        </command>
```

That works fine. However, the menu item contains the keyboard shortcut for the view, and I don't want it there. Is there any way to control it?

Comment: `the menu item` do you mean the command ?

Answer (score 0):

You might try writing a binding that has an empty key sequence for your command :

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key sequence=""
            commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"/>
</extension>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't seem to have worked though :(

Comment: Can you tell me what does your shortcut look like?

Comment: Alt+Shift+Q,X. This is the standard Eclipse shortcut. I didn't change it at all.